# Create Fluent Model with String Enum

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

Here is my Fluent Model

```
struct Ailment: PostgreSQLModel {

enum Frequency: String , Content {
    case regular = "Regular"
    case occasional = "Occasional"
    case incidentFound = "Incident Found"
}

var id: Int?

var ailment: String

var frequency: Frequency

var dateIdentified: Date?

var underMedication: Bool

var breifDescription: String

}
```

I am able to create Fluent Model with `Int Enum`, but it does not work with `String Enum`,

I am getting below Exception

```
Fatal error: Error raised at top level: ⚠️ DecodingError: Cannot initialize Frequency from invalid String value 1
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I tried this in newly created project. It throws the same exception.

Answer (score 3):

Referring [this Issue](https://github.com/vapor/vapor/issues/1736) it works with Vapor 3.0.6 and Fluent 3.0.0. The table should be created correct if your enum is conform to [ReflectionDecodable](https://github.com/vapor/core/blob/main/Sources/Core/CodableReflection/ReflectionDecodable.swift).

Comment: I am having the same issue and came across your answer. How exactly do you conform to ReflectionDecodable if the enum has more then 2 cases?

Comment: @KevinRenskers just check example: `Enums with two or more cases can conform.

enum Pet { case cat, dog }
extension Pet: ReflectionDecodable {
    static func reflectDecoded() -> (Pet, Pet) { return (.cat, .dog) }
}`

Comment: It say two OR MORE, just add the case to your enum. The `reflectDecoded()` just checks if two cases are the same or not. `enum Pet { case cat, dog, mouse } extension Pet: ReflectionDecodable { static func reflectDecoded() -> (Pet, Pet) { return (.cat, .dog) } }`

Comment: So what if I have 4 cases, then how does `reflectDecoded` work since it's only checking two cases, and returning the first 2? Sorry for the questions, I am just not grokking this part :)

Comment: It returns a tuple containing two distinct instances for your enum case type. That doesn`t mean that it only work with the two cases used in the method.